# Plaid API Liabilities GET Response

Tags: react-native, plaid

Hitting `liabilities/get` in the Plaid API in the Development environment - so using real data on a real account.  I'm looking at a loan type, mortgage sub-type.  I'm getting a lot of the response properties returned with a null value (other values obfuscated):

```
{
   "_userId": "****",
   "account_id": "***",
   "balances": {
      "available": null,
      "current": 999999.99,
      "iso_currency_code": "USD",
      "limit": null,
      "unofficial_currency_code": null
   },
   "details":
   {
      "account_id": "***",
      "account_number": "***",
      "current_late_fee": 0,
      "escrow_balance": 9999.99,
      "has_pmi": false,
      "has_prepayment_penalty": false,
      "interest_rate": {
         "percentage": 9.999,
         "type": null
      },
      "last_payment_amount": 9.9,
      "last_payment_date": "2024-03-04",
      "loan_term": null,
      "loan_type_description": "mortgage",
      "maturity_date": "2052-07-01",
      "next_monthly_payment": 9999.99,
      "next_payment_due_date": "2024-04-01",
      "origination_date": null,
      "origination_principal_amount": 0,
      "past_due_amount": 0,
      "ytd_interest_paid": 9999.99,
      "ytd_principal_paid": 9999.99
   },
   "subtype": "mortgage",
   "type": "loan"
}
```

I would expect these properties to have some kind of value.  Especially things like `loan_term`, `origination_date`, and `origination_principal_amount`, but instead they return `null` or `0`.

Is this just because I'm still working in the Development environment?  Is there a reason these values are `null` rather that providing the values I would expect?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Not every financial institution provides every field. You'll see different fields populated depending on the bank servicing the mortgage.